# Web app working fine but restarting computer returns: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm working on a Java web application and run locally on Tomcat. Everything works fine and shut down my (windows) laptop. When I next open the application and restart it it gives the following error: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

The (impracticable) fix that works most often is to uninstall Tomcat and then reinstall and magically everything works again. I'd like to understand what could be going wrong so I avoid this in the future

Tried Maven clean and build etc.

Comment: How do you start it, do you bind to an IP that changes by your DHCP or you bind to localhost? Please share some screenshots or give more details where you see the error? Do you start as a service ?

Comment: I run via Eclipse IDE and start by selecting Run > On Server. At work at the moment so cannot share screen shot at the minute but will do when I get home